# How to get individual values from an array Azure Logic apps

Tags: arrays, json, azure-logic-apps

I followed [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/form-recognizer/tutorial-form-recognizer-with-logic-apps) tutorial to get a sample Logic App that uses the Form Recognizer connector. The output is an array of key-value pairs of the data extracted from a pdf document or an image. I want to use some of the values that are extracted from the pdf in another connector.

The data extracted is something like this:

```
[
  {
    "id": "table_0",
    "columns": [
      {
        "header": [
          {
            "text": "Invoice Number",
            "boundingBox": [
              38.5,
              585.2,
              113.4,
              585.2,
              113.4,
              575.8,
              38.5,
              575.8
            ]
          }
        ],
        "entries": [
          [
            {
              "text": "7689302",
              "boundingBox": [
                38.5,
                549.8,
                77.3,
                549.8,
                77.3,
                536.2,
                38.5,
                536.2
              ],
              "confidence": 1
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "header": [
          {
            "text": "Invoice Date",
            "boundingBox": [
              139.7,
              585.2,
              198.5,
              585.2,
              198.5,
              575.8,
              139.7,
              575.8
            ]
          }
        ],
        "entries": [
          [
            {
              "text": "3/09/2015",
              "boundingBox": [
                139.7,
                548.1,
                184,
                548.1,
                184,
                536.2,
                139.7,
                536.2
              ],
              "confidence": 1
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "header": [
          {
            "text": "Invoice Due Date",
            "boundingBox": [
              240.5,
              585.2,
              321,
              585.2,
              321,
              575.8,
              240.5,
              575.8
            ]
          }
        ],
        "entries": [
          [
            {
              "text": "6/29/2016",
              "boundingBox": [
                240.5,
                549,
                284.8,
                549,
                284.8,
                536.2,
                240.5,
                536.2
              ],
              "confidence": 1
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "header": [
          {
            "text": "Charges",
            "boundingBox": [
              341.3,
              585.2,
              381.2,
              585.2,
              381.2,
              575.8,
              341.3,
              575.8
            ]
          }
        ],
        "entries": [
          [
            {
              "text": "$22,123.24",
              "boundingBox": [
                380.6,
                548.5,
                430.5,
                548.5,
                430.5,
                536.2,
                380.6,
                536.2
              ],
              "confidence": 1
            }
          ]
        ]
      },
      {
        "header": [
          {
            "text": "VAT ID",
            "boundingBox": [
              442.1,
              590,
              474.8,
              590,
              474.8,
              575.8,
              442.1,
              575.8
            ]
          }
        ],
        "entries": [
          [
            {
              "text": "QR",
              "boundingBox": [
                447.7,
                549.8,
                462.6,
                549.8,
                462.6,
                536.2,
                447.7,
                536.2
              ],
              "confidence": 1
            }
          ]
        ]
      }
    ]
  }
]
```

Comment: what do you wanna extract from output?

Comment: @AkshayBande The value of invoice number (7689302)

Answer (score 1):

If you just  want to get the value of `Invoice Number text value 7689302`, cause the compose output is json data, you could use json expression to get the value.

You could try `outputs('Compose')[0]['columns'][0]['entries'][0][0]['text']` to get the value.

[image]

[image]

Comment: With this approach, whenever the Invoice Number is not in the first position, you will get another value. It's not an scalable solution.

Comment: So suppose you want to get data from dynamic content directly, for now this is not able to implement it, cause if your data format is not fixed, logic app won't know what data you have, and if your format is fixed you could `parse json` to do it.

Comment: So did you mean your data format is not fixed?`whenever the Invoice Number is not in the first position`

Comment: The data extracted from the document may not always be the same, for that reason it would be nice to have a way to extract a value giving the name of the key you want to extract. I tried to do it with the Filter Array connector but it didn't work.

Comment: What do you mean not same, if your key-value level is not changed(means the position is not changed ) the expression should be ok, if changed suppose you have to use the code to solve it(could use azure function).